Not able to run Snowflake procedures parallelly in same time without waiting for one to complete
I am working with procedures and wanted to run multiple procedures in same time and don't want to wait for one to complete
------ My procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RUNFORMINUTE()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.11'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'main'
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '# The Snowpark package is required for Python Worksheets. 
# You can add more packages by selecting them using the Packages control and then importing them.

import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
import time

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    # Your code goes here, inside the "main" handler.

    start_time = time.time()
    duration = 15  # 60 seconds
    
    while True:
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - start_time

        if elapsed_time >= duration:
            break
        time.sleep(1) 
    
    return "success"
';

--- and here is the snow park code where I am trying to run same multiple time
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
 
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    # Your code goes here, inside the "main" handler.
 
    s1 = session.sql("call RUNFORMINUTE();  call RUNFORMINUTE();")
    
    s1.collect()
    return "success";

How can I run snowflake procedures parallelly in same time?

I'm not sure if this is the answer or not, but what if you used collect_nowait instead of collect and then separated the statements out.  So, s1 and s2, each executed with collect_nowait separately.  You'd then need to poll the asyncjob until they are both done before returning a success, though.

I recommend pasting the code that you used explicitly into the answer to your question, so that others have more than just my rambling comment to guide them.
